# How to customize this button?

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this link

http://test2.dac-proiect.ro/wp

At the bottom (footer) to find a Newsletter ... who has a problem, a submit button that does not look good at all ... and I do not understand what.

I have installed a theme and when I entered date widget worked without problems ... now does not look good.

Can you help me please give it a shape?

I tried to make some changes in the CSS code but without success.

Comment: Never give site link as a case study because once it's fixed it's of no use to anyone, and how you would like the submit button to appear??

Comment: You can style buttons, but it would be better to add a span  (with a class for styling) with a javascript event to control the processing. Wordpress in general does not use buttons, so there should be no button styling done in your existing css, hence it looks like just another button. You are also a limited as to how much you can style a button.

Comment: This question is completely dependent on how you want the button to look. It's impossible to answer without knowing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to the submit button..

```
width: 100px;
height: 30px;
line-height: 1px;
float: right;
```

it looks like below one after applying ..

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this.,

```css
    #mc4wp-form-1 input[type="submit"] {
      height: 35px;
      width:80px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      border: none;
      line-height: 10px;
      background-color:white;
    }
    #mc4wp-form-1 input[type="submit"]:hover {
          background-color:red;
          color:white;
       }
body{
  background-color:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="mc4wp-form-1">
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
 </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add this in your CSS file (http://test2.dac-proiect.ro/wp/wp-content/themes/mix/css/template.css).

```
.mc4wp-form form p input[type="submit"], form.mc4wp-form p input[type="submit"] {
float: left;
padding: 5px 0 !important;
width: 100%;
line-height: 35px;
```

}